# Can't get the right CRC CCiTT in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the 16 bit CRC CCITT FALSE.
I'm using this page to check it.

http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

And this is my code

```
unsigned int16 crc16_CCITT(unsigned int8 *data, unsigned int16 len)//CRC16 CCITT False
{
   unsigned int16 crc = 0xFFFF;

   for(unsigned int16 j = len; j > 0; j--)
   {
      crc ^= *data++;

      for(unsigned int8 i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      {
         if(crc & 1)
         {
            //crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8401; // 0x8401 is the reflection of 0x1021
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0x1021;
         }   
         else
         {
            crc >>= 1;
         }   
      }
   }
   return (crc);
}
```

As you can see I already tried by reflecting the polynomial and didn't work either.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I already used this routine with the 16bit ARC CRC.(0x8005) and works ok.

Comment: Do you need to reflect the polynomial too?

Comment: No, according to that page nothing is reflected, I just tried because I runned out of ideas.

Comment: BTW, 0x1021 reversed is 0x8408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try shifting the bits the other way:

```
uint16_t crc16_CCITT (unsigned char *ptr, int count)
{
   uint16_t crc = 0xffff;
   int i = 0;

   while (--count >= 0)
   {
      crc = crc ^ (uint16_t )*ptr++ << 8;
      for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
      {
         if (crc & 0x8000)
         {
            crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x1021;
         }
         else
         {
            crc = crc << 1;
         }
      }
   }
   return crc;
}
```

Comment: It works for two bytes of data 0x00,0x00 but for other doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give us an example or two of input data, expected result, actual result? My results match CRC CCITT FALSE on the web page you referenced.

Comment: 0x00 0x02 0x03 0x25 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x14 0x00 0x36 should be 0xB84A and I get 0xF352 with start value of 0xFFFF, polynomial 0x1021 as in your code.

Comment: I get 0xb84a for that input of 10 bytes, so something else is wrong in your setup.

Comment: I checked mi code and I missed the <<8; now it works.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned int16` and `unsigned int8` are ambiguous. It's better to change them to `uint16`,`uint8` or `unsigned short`,`unsigned char`. In many header files, int16 is defined as signed short and int8 is defined as signed char.

Comment: or even better, to the standard ones `uint16_t` and `uint8_t`

Comment: Is 8 bit microcontroller C, not x86 C and, as I said, the routine already worked with another polynomial.